# Updating a group of .net applications

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ftp, clickonce

I have a group of .Net desktop applications that i worked on in c#, i publish the applications to an FTP server and on each run the application checks if a newer version is available.

now i want to write a new application that handles the updates for all applications, and i want it to do the following

- list all installed applications in a grid and display the current
  versions.
- display the non installed applications that are available on the
  server
- options to uninstall the application or install it or update it if a newer version is availabe

now i can manage everything above except for the update part, do i have to uninstall the application and then install the newer version from the ftp sever programmatically?

can you please give me some guides on this subject?

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you are doing what most people end up doing with ClickOnce - having your application update before start-up and forcing the minimum version to be the current version.

If that's the case, I would solve your update problem with a query string parameter. In the ClickOnce options there is a checkbox, "Allow URL parameters to be passed to the application". Turn that on for all your apps. Then change them to look at the query string for an "updateonly" parameter. If it exists, exit the app.

Then from your updater app all you have to do is open the url (with the "updateonly" parameter) to an application manifest. The app will start, update itself, and shut itself down after updating.